# Mot pour « action de jeter à la poubelle »

Tags: expressions, demande-de-mot, synonymes

Existe-t-il un mot pour signifier « action de jeter à la poubelle » ?

Edit: Ayant posé la question rapidement et n'ayant alors pas bien pris en compte la diversité des contextes possibles pour cette expression, j'ai omis de préciser que je souhaite l'employer dans le contexte du recyclage des déchets organiques.

De plus, le fait que la réponse puisse être constituée de plus d'un mot n'est pas un problème, contrairement à ce que ma question a certainement laissé entendre.

Cependant, la richesse et l'imaginativité de vos réponses, en écho au manque de précision de la question posée, a fourni de nombreuses réponses possibles dans de nombreux contextes, ce qui s'est révélé fort utile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pas exactement, mais la « *[mise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mise) au rancart* » à partir de « *[mettre au rancart](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rancart)* »<sup>1</sup> est intéressante:

> Pop., fam. *Jeter, mettre au rancart*. ,,Mettre au rebut`` (Ac. 1878,
>   1935). *Et notre vie de grandes fillettes orphelines après (...) du
>   passé comme ça, vécu ensemble (...) ça ne se jette pas au rancard
>   comme une chemise sale* (E. de Goncourt, *Faustin*,1882, p. 33).
>
> [ TLFi ]

---

Il y a aussi immédiatement après le moment du « [jet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jet) » pourrait-on dire, l'« action d'être », présente dans un des sens du nom [*débarras*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9barras) (normalement davantage au figuré):

> Fait, action d'être [débarrassé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9barrasser) de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose.
>
> [ TLFi ]

La poubelle n'est pas spécifiquement visée par le débarras et il s'agit d'un état (de désencombrement). Mais la locution *jeter à/dans la [poubelle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poubelle)* signifie aussi justement *se débarrasser de qqc.* (à la forme pronominale); la nuance entre *se débarrasser* et l'action d'être débarrassé (le débarras), semble parfois ténue, comme ici, mais elle existe puisque quelqu'un d'autre pourrait jeter à notre place, et donc nous débarrasser d'un fardeau, par exemple.

Une curiosité: en anglais *Collins* décide de rendre « [*discard*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/discard) » par *se débarrasser de* (*throw out*), un choix intéressant si l'on compare avec « [*throw away*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/throw-away) » pour jeter, et l'*écart*.

---

<sub>1. Voir aussi [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/rancart) et [écart (2)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9cart) (subst. masc. « *Action d'écarter, de rejeter une ou plusieurs cartes*[...] ») au *TLFi*. ll s'agit de sens plus ou moins contemporains des déverbaux d'é*carter*: *écart* - *re-écart* - *récart* - *rancart*, mais voir aussi, différent, [*raccard*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raccard) (grenier).</sub>

Comment: "Mettre au rebut", défini par le dictionnaire "l'internaute" comme "Rejeter, considérer comme sans valeur", me semble l'expression la plus appropriée dans le contexte des déchets. Bien que cela soit une expression plutôt qu'un seul et unique mot, je vais donc retenir "mise au rebut". Merci.

Comment: De rien! Oui, donc j'avais ça sous les yeux dans la définition de _mettre au rancart_ mais j'ai pas pensé le présenter en tant que tel. Tant mieux si c'est utile! Merci!

Answer (score 10):

Dans le contexte informatique, on utilise le plus souvent le verbe d'action *supprimer*.
Hors de ce contexte, c'est l'expression que tu cites qui est presque toujours utilisée, parfois simplement abrégée *jeter*, la poubelle étant implicite.

On rencontre parfois à l'oral *[benner](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/benner)* voire *balancer*, mais c'est familier.

---

Pour répondre plus précisément à la question posée qui recherche un nom d'action plutôt qu'un verbe :

Pour la forme substantive, on a moins de choix car toutes ne sont pas utilisées. On a en effet **suppression**, mais on ne parle jamais *du jet d'un objet* (pour désigner l'action de le jeter) ni du *"bennage"*.

Hors du contexte informatique, cependant, il me semble qu'il n'y a pas de terme correspondant à ce que tu recherches.

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu le terme "bennage". A l'oral, du moins.

Answer (score 3):

Outside of the tech context (and I don't read your question as asking specifically for one context or the other), there's

> [l'élimination](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/%C3%A9limination) des déchets.

And then there's le Robert-Micro's I(3) sense of "balayer" (Faire disparaitre) and the noun given for the action of to "balayer": = "**un/le balayage**."

Comment: Le concept d'"élimination" me semble trop extrême dans le contexte où je souhaite l'employer.

Answer (score 1):

Le néologisme *poubelliser* est de plus en plus employé, même s'il n'a pas rejoint l'emploi papier une [recherche google](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=poubelliser&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl#as_qdr=all&q=poubelliser) montre que je ne suis pas la seule à l'employer, et pas uniquement dans un contexte informatique.
À partir de là on a fait le substantif [poubellisation](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poubellisation), mais dont l'usage se rencontre aussi plus sur l'internet que sur le papier.

Comment: Le substantif "poubellisation" est intéressant mais je vais attendre une dizaine d'année avant de l'employer dans un document officiel. Merci cependant pour me l'avoir fait découvrir.

Answer (score 1):

*Balancer*.

Exemple:

> Tu as fait quoi de ta vieille TV?
>   — Je l'ai balancée.

C'est familier mais encore assez correct.

Ou bien, mais c'est plus d'un mot, tu peux aussi dire : « foutre en l'air ».

Comment: Comme toi, j'avais au départ cherché dans les verbes d'action. Mais c'est un *nom* qu'on cherche... Moi aussi j'aimais bien *balancer*, mais y'a pas de *balançage*... ^^

Answer (score 1):

On peut utiliser tout simplement **poubelle**:

> — Et ça qu'est ce que j'en fait ?
>
> — Poubelle !

Answer (score 1):

Dans le contexte du recyclage des déchets, qu'ils soient organiques ou non, le simple `tri` ou bien l'utilisation du verbe `trier` peuvent être utilisés.

Dans une conversation, si quelqu'un demande "Qu'est-ce que je fais de mes déchets ?" et qu'on lui réponds "tri les." Il comprendra qu'il s'agit d'un `tri sélectif` en vue d'un prochain recyclage. 
Dans le langage courant, on peut même dire `"ça part au tri"` pour indiquer qu'on va le jeter à la poubelle, mais pas n'importe quelle poubelle.
Pour ce qui est du verbe `trier`. Trier ses déchets signifie les séparer, les trier par catégories en vue de les jeter dans la poubelle adéquat pour les recycler (pour des végétaux, ils ne s'agira pas d'une poubelle mais plutôt d'un bac à composte).

On put donc tout simplement dire, `"Je trie mes déchets"`. Tout le monde comprendra qu'il s'agit de mettre à la poubelle afin que les déchets soient recyclés. De plus, le terme n'est pas familier du tout.

Saches aussi qu'on peut détourner ce mot pour parler d'autre chose. Par exemple, qu'on on quitte quelqu'un et qu'on dit "il/elle est parti(e) au tri sélectif". Une façon humoristique de dire qu'on a quitté la personne.

Si on parle de recyclage, je te conseille de jeter un œil au terme "revalorisation des déchets".

Sinon, pour le simple fait de jeter quelque chose, comme dit plus haut, on peut le "balancer", "bazarder", "benner", "virer"...